# Combine all values and remove duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, unique, delimited

How combine this array and remove duplicate values?
Thank you!

```
  array (size=17)
  0 => string 'Black' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Blue' (length=4)
  2 => string 'Burgundy' (length=8)
  3 => string 'Glow' (length=4)
  4 => string 'Granite' (length=7)
  5 => string 'Green' (length=5)
  6 => string 'Lime' (length=4)
  7 => string 'Natural' (length=7)
  8 => string 'Orange' (length=6)
  9 => string 'Pink' (length=4)
  10 => string 'Purple' (length=6)
  11 => string 'Red' (length=3)
  12 => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  13 => string 'Teal' (length=4)
  14 => string 'Violet' (length=6)
  15 => string 'White' (length=5)
  16 => string 'Yellow' (length=6)
```

Thank you, your code worked perfectly.

I'm still missing something because I don't get what I want.

The values (color names) are in the select form, but when a value other than 'Filter by Color' is selected, the 'id' is what pass instead of the 'text'. To make things easy, here is the complete code.

Thank you.

```
$Sql_product_colors = ("SELECT COUNT(p.products_id) AS id, pia.product_filter_colors FROM products p LEFT JOIN products_imprint_areas pia on p.products_id = pia.products_id
         WHERE p.products_id > '1'
         AND pia.product_filter_colors IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY product_filter_colors
         ORDER BY product_filter_colors asc");
         $sort_list_colors = array();
         $product_filter_colors = tep_db_query($Sql_product_colors) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($product_filter_colors)) {
    $arrColor = explode(',', $row[1]);                             
    $arrColors=array_filter(array_map('trim', $arrColor));          
    $sort_list_color = array_merge($sort_list_colors,$arrColors); 
    $sort_list_colors = array_unique($sort_list_color);
    sort($sort_list_colors);
      }
                    $sort_list_colors[0] ='Filter by Color';
                    $sort_list_colors[] ='&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row[$sort_list_colors].' &nbsp;&nbsp;(' .$sort_list_colors['count'].')';

        if(count($sort_list_colors)>0)
                 {
                     foreach($sort_list_colors as $id=>$text) {
                      $sort_range_colors[] = array('id' => $id, 'text' => $text);
                     }
                 }
// -------------------------------------- Select form
        echo '<td align="center" width="25%" valign="middle"><div class="styled-select">' . tep_draw_form('colors_sort', htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 'get') . '';
        echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('colors_sort', $sort_range_colors, (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['colors_sort']) ? $HTTP_GET_VARS['colors_sort'] : ''), 'onchange="this.form.submit()"');
        echo '</form></div></td>';
```

This is the function tep_draw_pull_down_menu. Thank you.

```
 function tep_draw_pull_down_menu($name, $values, $default = '', $parameters = '', $required = false) {
    $field = '<select name="' . tep_output_string($name) . '"';
    if (tep_not_null($parameters)) $field .= ' ' . $parameters;
    $field .= '>';
    if (empty($default) && isset($GLOBALS[$name])) $default = stripslashes($GLOBALS[$name]);
    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($values); $i<$n; $i++) {
      $field .= '<option value="' . tep_output_string($values[$i]['id']) . '"';
      if ($default == $values[$i]['id']) {
        $field .= ' SELECTED';
      }
      $field .= '>' . tep_output_string($values[$i]['text'], array('"' => '&quot;', '\'' => '&#039;', '<' => '&lt;', '>' => '&gt;')) . '</option>';
    }
    $field .= '</select>';
    if ($required == true) $field .= TEXT_FIELD_REQUIRED;
    return $field;
  }
```

Comment: This question would be MUCH clearer if we cpuld see some sample db rows and your exact desired output from your sample data.  A [mcve] is absolutely vital for creating a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [*array_merge*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) then [*array_unique*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php),

```
$colors = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter_colors)) {
    $arrColors = explode(',', $row[1]);
    $colors = array_merge($colors,$arrColors);
}
$colors = array_unique($colors);
```

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I'm still missing something. I posted the complete code. Thank you.

Comment: Its depend on how you have designed your function `tep_draw_pull_down_menu` & are you passing params as it required?

Comment: I posted the function here, hope to get this fixed.

Comment: Rikesh, can you take a look at the function and see what error I'm doing on my code please? Thanks!